# Get first subsequent DayOfWeek from list

Tags: java, datetime, kotlin, java-time, dayofweek

For a schedule app I need to determine the first day after today from a list, going forwards. So for example:

```
DayOfWeek today -> SATURDAY
val list1 = listOf(MONDAY, TUESDAY, FRIDAY)

DayOfWeek today -> WEDNESDAY
val list2 = listOf(TUESDAY)
```

The logic would then have to give me MONDAY for list1 and TUESDAY for list2. I am aware of the `.plusDays()` function on the DayOfWeek enum class and the `TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame()` but you then have to supply a DayOfWeek, which I don't know since I'm trying to find it inside the list.

Comment: If today were `MONDAY`, and the list has `MONDAY` and `TUESDAY`, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: TUESDAY, since it's the first subsequent next day after monday. (Deleted my previous wrong comment).

Comment: But Ole V.V.'s answer produces MONDAY, and you accepted it?

Comment: I simplified my question, so it would focus on the algoritm / which collection function to use. Next and nextOrSame can both be usefull for my logic. Your and Olle answers guided me enough in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    List<DayOfWeek> list = List.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);
    
    DayOfWeek first = Collections.min(list,
            Comparator.comparing(dow -> today.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dow))));
    System.out.println(first);
```

Output when running today (Saturday in my time zone):

> MONDAY

I am querying the minimum using a comparator that compares the date of the next occurrence of that day of week (today if today happens to be that day). Since Monday comes first, this is regarded as the minimum. I am indirectly calling the `TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame()` method that you mentioned on each member of your list. It may not be the most time efficient approach, but for 19 out of 20 purposes I’m sure it’s fine. And it gives code that is short and that I find readable, that’s more important.

If today is Wednesday? Let’s just try setting `today` to next Wednesday:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.JUNE, 23);
```

Now output is:

> FRIDAY

Comment: Correct...Also, with `import static java.time.DayOfWeek.*;`, you can use `MONDAY` ,`TUESDAY` etc. directly,

Comment: Thanks, this seem to work. Do you happen to know a Kotlin variant of your answer? My codebase is fully Kotlin so prefer to use a Kotlin alternative. If not I'll stick with good old Java :)

Comment: Sorry, I don’t write Kotlin. I would not have expected a translation to be hard for someone who does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [Ole V.V.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68044403/5133585), translated into Kotlin as a function.

```
fun nextWeekDayInList(list: List<DayOfWeek>, today: LocalDate) =
    list.minByOrNull { dow ->
        today.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dow))
    }
```

This will return `null` if the list is empty.

Usage:

```
println(nextWeekDayInList(
    listOf(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY),
    today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
))
```

Judging from [your recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044346/get-first-subsequent-dayofweek-from-list?noredirect=1#comment120267596_68044346), `next` might be more suitable than `nextOrSame`.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried with .first{..}, takeIf{..}, filterIndexed{..} and some other collection functions, but .minByOrNull{..} seems the correct one, didnt knew it existed!

Answer (score 1):

I am late, but I have created a solution. So, posting it.

```
package com.ubaid;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<DayOfWeek> list = List.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);

        DayOfWeek nextDay = getFirstDayInListAfterTodayGoingForward(list);

        //will print MONDAY (today is SATURDAY)
        log.debug(String.valueOf(nextDay));

        list = List.of(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY);

        nextDay = getFirstDayInListAfterTodayGoingForward(list);
        //will print TUESDAY (today is SATURDAY)
        log.debug(String.valueOf(nextDay));
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param list of days of week
     * @return first day of week after today or today if today is present in the list
     */
    private static DayOfWeek getFirstDayInListAfterTodayGoingForward(List<DayOfWeek> list) {

        //MONDAY value is 1
        //  .
        //  .
        //SUNDAY value is 7

        //getting today value
        int todayVal = DayOfWeek.from(LocalDate.now()).getValue();

        //sort the DAYS according to their ordinal values
        List<Integer> daysInListVal = list
            .stream()
            .map(DayOfWeek::getValue)
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (daysInListVal.contains(todayVal)) {
            return DayOfWeek.of(todayVal);
        }

        //now get the DAY value which is next to today DAY
        //If next value is not present then pick the first item of sorted list
        return daysInListVal
            .stream()
            .filter(dayInList -> dayInList > todayVal)
            .findFirst()
            .map(DayOfWeek::of)
            .orElse(DayOfWeek.of(daysInListVal.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow()));
    }
}
```